What does rows processed mean in the cockroachDB UI/console?
Here is a screenshot of the DB console for a cockroachDB cluster, what does 7.5 writes mean in this case? This application is a Spring Boot application and is doing batched writes.
Is 7.5 the size of the batch per insert? is it doing 7.5 batch inserts? or inserting 7.5 rows? What does 0.5 writes even represent?


what you are seeing in the console are aggregated stats for that specific insert statement / fingerprint. The execution count indicates that that statement has run 1.8 million times (note that this includes retries) and on average each time it does 7.5 writes (writing to a single row).
Hope that helps, see Statements Page for more details.
